# How to put spacing between TBODY elements

Tags: html, css

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
    <tfoot>
        <tr><td>footer</td></tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Body 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body 1</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Body 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body 2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Body 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body 3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'd like to put some spacing between each tbody element, but padding and margin have no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: Is is right to repeat 'tbody' tags? What I have seen always is all the "<tr>..</tr>" are inside a single "tbody' tag.

Comment: Yes this is valid. The spec says: <!ELEMENT TABLE - - (CAPTION?, (COL*|COLGROUP*), THEAD?, TFOOT?, TBODY+)> meaning that there has to be one or more tbodies.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try this, if you don't mind not having borders.

```
<style>
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tbody {
  border-top: 15px solid white;
}
</style>

<table>
    <tfoot>
        <tr><td>footer</td></tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Body 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body 1</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Body 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body 2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Body 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body 3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Try border-top: 15px solid transparent;

Comment: Wanted to stress this. Use `transparent` as the border color. What @SteveAlmond said.

Comment: if the table/tbody/tr/td has a background-color, setting the border color to `transparent` will give it the background-color of the element, essentially indisinguishable from the element's body. You would need to explicitly color the border the color you want it to appear as (to make it supposedly invisible)

Answer (score 104):

Something like this will work, depending on your browser support requirements:

```
tbody::before
{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 15px;

}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that works when your cells have a background that the space should not have.

Comment: This worked well for me. Are there any drawbacks? Also, why two colons?

Comment: @nh2: double-colons are for pseudo-content and single-colon is for pseudo-selectors. It's an update to the CSS syntax. Everything used to just use the single colon. Older browsers don't support double colon (like, IE <=8).

Comment: Isn't it safer to use `display: table-row;`?

Answer (score 27):

People will always have controversial opinions about using empty table elements to layout a page (as evidenced by this answer's downvote).  I recognize this, but sometimes its easier to use them this way when you are working in a "**quick and dirty**" way.

I've used empty rows in past projects to space groups of table rows.  I assigned the spacer rows a css class of their own and defined a height for that class that acted as a top and bottom margin for that group of table rows.

```
    .separator{
             height: 50px;
    }

   <table>
           <tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr>

           <tr class="separator" colspan="2"></tr>

           <tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr>

           <tr class="separator" colspan="2"></tr>

           tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr>
   </table>
```

<strike>If you don't have borders on your table cells,</strike> you could also define a height to your typical cell or row in your style sheet that evenly spaces out all rows of your table.

```
tr{
   height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: well if you're going to be adding extra markup, why not just put a class on the first row of each tbody?

Comment: Well, that could be because the rows are generated code, and adding a separate row in the markup might be more maintainable than creating a special case for the first row of generated content.

Comment: Downvote all you want, but this is the only solution without drawbacks -- and even if it does violate seperation, an empty row isn't that big of a deal IMO.

Comment: Without drawbacks, my butt!  Try using a screenreader on this and notice the incorrect row counts.  Better yet, try copying and pasting the table into a spreadsheet.  You'll be reformatting for hours if you have a lot of content.

Tables are meant to display data (and be extremely accessible), not shim presentation between sections.

Comment: It's only visual. Keep in mind that html are also documents that can be processed, therefore content inside them should be well formatted. As mentioned above, copy-paste table or usage of screen reader will just fail. Such design should not be encouraged. ::content solution is better cause it does not mess up the markup.

Answer (score 21):

I had been having trouble with cross-browser support for spacing multiple `<tbody>`'s using the `::before` pseudo-selector if any `<td>`'s had a `rowspan`.

Basically, if your `<tbody>` is structured like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>td 1</td>
        <td rowspan"2">td 2</td>
        <td>td 3</td>
        <td>td 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>td 1</td>
        <td>td 2</td>
        <td>td 4</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

...and your `::before` pseudo-selector displays the content as a `block` like this:

```
tbody::before
{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
}
```

...then this will cause the table to cut off any columns that use `rowspan`.

The solution is to style `::before` pseudo as a `table-row`:

```
tbody::before
{
    content: '';
    display: table-row;
    height: 10px;
}
```

This should have good cross-browser support.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6e8vxnpn/)

Comment: Looking at the Fiddle, I see no differences between the 2 options. In which browsers did you have issues with this?

Comment: 7 years have passed, I think the noticeable differences in the fiddle have now been overcome by the updates of the internal engines of the browsers.

Answer (score 10):

Here's another possibility that relies on :first-child which is not available in all browsers:

```
<style>
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tbody tr:first-child td {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

</style>

<table>
    <tfoot>
        <tr><td>footer</td></tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Body 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body 1</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Body 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body 2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Body 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body 3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This one won't work very well if you have anything that happens to rely on the position of the content relative to the size of the cell, like box-shadow, background images, or pretty much anything else.

Comment: Just to clarify for others finding this answer on google, I presume as this was written in 2008, this answer now (2015) has full support across all major browsers? At least checking on caniuse.com first-child seems well supported?

Answer (score 4):

Of all of the answers given above, only djenson47's answers retain [separation of presentation and content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content). The drawback of the **collapsed border model** method is that you can no longer use the table's *border* or *cellspacing* attributes to separate the individual cells. You could argue that this is a good thing, and there are some workarounds, but it can be a pain. So I think the *first-child* method is the most elegant.

Alternatively, you could also set your TBODY class' *overflow* property to anything other than "visible." This method allows you to retain a separated borders model as well:

```
<style>
tbody {
    overflow: auto;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
</style>
<table>
    <tfoot>
        <tr><td>footer</td></tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Body 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body 1</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Body 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body 2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Body 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body 3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I was looking to do something similar, this is perfect for me

Comment: It seems like this doesn't work, I tried using a 50px border-top and nothing happened: https://jsfiddle.net/stramin/zrsq0dmk/

Answer (score 4):

You can use `border-spacing` in a table with table row groups to add a space between those groups. Though, I don't think there is a way to specify which groups are spaced and which are not.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    ...
  </head>
  <tbody>
    ...
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    ...
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    ...
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
  border-spacing: 0px 10px; /* h-spacing v-spacing */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just set `display` as `block` and it will work.

```
table tbody{
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: this answer should be the accepted answer because is the only one that allows to use a bordered tbody with "no-border" columns.

Comment: `display:block` breaks the column alignment between tbody elements.  You no longer get the benefit of the table layout engine

Answer (score 4):

Because padding can be applied to TD's, you can do a trick with the + sign. Then it will be possible to give a top padding to the TD's of the first TR of a tbody:

```
// The first row will have a top padding
table tbody + tbody tr td {
    padding-top: 20px;
}

// The rest of the rows should not have a padding
table tbody + tbody tr + tr td {
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

I have added the "tbody + tbody" so the first tbody won't have a top padding. However, it's not required.

As far as I know there are no drawbacks :), though didn't test the older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

### NEW ANSWER

You can use as many `<tbody>` tags as you like. I didn't realize that was ok by W3C until now. Not to say my below solution doesn't work (it does), but to do what you're trying to do, assign your `<tbody>` tags classes and then reference their individual `<td>` tags through CSS like so:

```
table tbody.yourClass td {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

and your HTML thusly:

```
<table> 
<tbody>
<tr><td>Text</td></tr>
<tr><td>Text</td></tr>
<tr><td>Text</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tbody class="yourClass">    
<tr><td>Text</td></tr>
<tr><td>Text</td></tr>
<tr><td>Text</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Text</td></tr>
<tr><td>Text</td></tr>
<tr><td>Text</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Try that guy out :)

### OLD ANSWER

whatever you do, DON'T insert blank rows...

you shouldn't have more than 1 tbody element in your table. what you can do is set the class or id attribute in your `<tr>` elements and give their corresponding `<td>` tags padding:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr.yourClass td {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

You can even assign the top and bottom `<tr>`'s an additional class so that they only do top or bottom padding, respectively:

```
tr.yourClass.topClass td {
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}

tr.yourClass.bottomClass td {
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

and in your HTML, your `<tr>` tag would look like this:

```
<table> 
<tbody>
<tr><td>Text</td></tr>
<tr><td>Text</td></tr>
<tr><td>Text</td></tr>
<tr class="yourClass topClass"><td>Text</td></tr>
<tr class="yourClass"><td>Text</td></tr>
<tr class="yourClass bottomClass"><td>Text</td></tr>
<tr><td>Text</td></tr>
<tr><td>Text</td></tr>
<tr><td>Text</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

djensen47 answer works great for newer browsers, however, as it was pointed out, IE7 it does not work in.

My workaround for this issue to support the older browsers was to wrap each cells contents inside a div.  Then add a margin-top to the div.

```
<table class="tbl">
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr><td><div></div></td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.tbl tr td div {
    height:30px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

The height setting keeps the cells at least 30px high to prevent any cell coloring used inside the div from collapsing around the text.  The margin-top creates the desired space by making the entire row taller.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this while trying to solve it myself. I had success with putting a `<br>` tag right before the closing `</tbody>` tag. It is a purely visual fix, but seems to work on most browsers I tested.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <br>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Should be accessible as well.

Answer (score 0):

With credit to everyone else who answered first ...

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 50%;
}
tbody:before {
  content: "";
  display:block;
  border-top: 15px solid white;
}
tbody tr {
  border-color: #000;
  border-style: solid;
}
tbody tr:first-of-type{
  border-width: 2px 2px 0 2px;
}
tbody tr:nth-of-type(1n+2){
  border-width: 0 2px 0 2px;
}
tbody tr:last-of-type{
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 2px;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
td {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">One</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Two</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```