# Padding on tbody

Tags: html, css, vbulletin

I'm using vBulletin to style a forum which primarily uses tables to style the site. How would I go about using padding on a `tbody` to space the content away from the border?

Here you can see a picture of my main site where the content is pushed 5px away from the border:

[image]

Whereas on vBulletin, adding padding on `tbody` doesn't push the content away:

[image]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Method 1**
You have a couple different options:

```
tbody:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Adding this basically "inserts" content before the end. It's sort of a "quick-n-dirty" fix. 

**Method 2**
Another option is giving your `table` a `border-collapse: collapse` and then giving your `tbody` a border value:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tbody {
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

Both of these methods have drawbacks, however. The before selector might not work in IE7, and requires a `!DOCTYPE` to work in IE8. The second method can sometimes be a bit touchy, depending on the rest of your css. Be sure to have a `!DOCTYPE`

Comment: For IE8 compatibility you will need to use single colons. Otherwise the double colon syntax is only supported by IE9 and later.

Comment: In IE9, this does not seem to be applying the height for me. It works in Chrome and IE11, but not IE9. If I change content to something like "xyz", the characters show up so the style is definitely being applied, but the height simply isn't putting that many pixels of space in there.

Comment: What about using pseudo elements :first-child :last-child on the tr within tbody. More info at http://stackoverflow.com/a/294925/339803

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty col and/or row with padded cells.

Adding :before content to `tbody` may not have the effect you're looking for. It may not push borders around as you think or even other cells or col or row groups. In general do not try to put anything outside a cell in a table, you're asking for trouble.