# in a table with more than one tbody how to create some space between the tbody elements

Tags: css, html-table

I'm not having any success trying to create some space, a gap, between the tbody sections of a table that contains multiple tbody elements.   How do do it?

```
        <table>
        <thead></thead>


        <tbody>
           .
           .
           .
        </tbody>

        // create a gap here

        <tbody>
            .
           .
           .
        </tbody>



        <tfoot></tfoot>
        </table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to put spacing between TBODY elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294885/how-to-put-spacing-between-tbody-elements)

Comment: Agreed, I'll delete it as a duplicate.

Comment: Oops. Cannot delete it.

Comment: Actually, the accepted answer there doesn't work in all browsers, so the question is really still an open question.

Comment: Fair point @Tim -- retracting my close vote.

Comment: I often use sibling selectors for cases like this. `tbody + tbody { ... }` selects a tbody that follows another tbody (so it doesn't select the first one) and give it margin-top.  That way there is space between each tbody, but no space above the first one. (not tested with tbody, therefore I'm posting as a comment, not an answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try some css

```
table tbody {
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

or maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294885/how-to-put-spacing-between-tbody-elements) will help you

Comment: Thanks. Padding is not working but that other answer gave some good options.

Answer (score 0):

This works, except you lose your borders.

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tbody {
  border-top: 10px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<thead></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>text1</td></tr>
...
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
...
<tr><td>text2</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot></tfoot>
```

or:

```
<thead></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>text1</td></tr>
...
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
...
<tr><td>text2</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot></tfoot>
```